# Redis - which node is being chosen by StackExchange library?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

In Redis we're connecting to a 6 node setup with 3 pairs of master/slaves.

We're using StackExchange.Redis version 1.2.6 for .NET.

Our connectionstring is as following:
1.1.1.1:6379,2.2.2.2:6379,3.3.3.3:6379,4.4.4.4:6379,5.5.5.5:6379,6.6.6.6:6379

How does the library decide what node to try and connect to?

> Endpoint 1.1.1.1:6379 serving hashslot 983 is not reachable at this
> point of time. Please check connectTimeout value. If it is low, try
> increasing it to give the ConnectionMultiplexer a chance to recover
> from the network disconnect.

It is *always* 1.1.1.1:6379 that we're seeing this error from.

Are we only getting errors for the first node because it's always trying to reach the first node we've provided in the connectionstring (do the order of IPs matter?), or could it be because of underlying issues with that specific master/slave relationship?